# array elements as argument in functions

Tags: arrays, swift, func

New to swift. We have

```
var b : [Double] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var c = 5
```

I want to call func xyz with first c elements of b.

`var a = xyz(b[0...c])` - doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Range` to pick in an array generates an `ArraySlice`, not an `Array`.

So if you wish to pass this "slice" to a function:

```
var b : [Double] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var c = 5

let slice = b[0...c]
```

you have to make your function accept an `ArraySlice` with the right type:

```
func xyz(chunk: ArraySlice<Double>) {
    print(chunk)
}

xyz(slice)
```

But if you want to just use normal arrays, make your function accept an array, and transform the slice into an array when calling the function:

```
func xyz(chunk: [Double]) {
    print(chunk)
}

xyz(Array(slice))
```

Comment: thanks!
func xyz(chunk: [Double]) -> [Double]
i have var y : Double
how can i assign to y last element of xyz's [Double] ?

Comment: To get the last element, do `array.last`. It works with arrays and arrayslices. It returns an optional so you also have to (safely) unwrap it. You could also do `[array.count-1...array.count-1]` but it's horrible. ;)

Comment: Eric, what if b is a struct that contains x : Double. And i want again to call a func :
xyz(b[0 ... 5].x) - how to manage this? Thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your example. Maybe you should post a new question with detailed explanations about what you want to achieve (and link to this page in your question). I - or someone else - will be able to answer with details if you give a detailed example. Here in comments it's really not a convenient place to do that. :)